# Parse Push Notification not working on REAL Device but working on Emulator

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

i am working on a project, Currently using parse Push Notification, When i run the app on emulator, The notification works perfectly but Not working on my Samsung galaxy Note 11 and other android devices.

What could be the cause of the problem?

Here is my Permission :

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.packageName.www.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.packageName.www.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

**Here is my Receiver Tags**

```
<service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="com.packageName.www" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: So, with your real Android device hooked up, your broadcast receiver doesn't receive anything? Any logcats perhaps?

Comment: @alpinescrambler    Check this    `<receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>`

Comment: `<receiver
            android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="com.mypackageName.www" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>`

Comment: Can you update your question and paste it there? Also paste your permissions in your manifest file

Comment: Also, have checked in Parse.Com's console if the message was actually sent out? In fact, you can even send a "test message" from there.

Comment: Yeah. I have enabled client push..

Comment: Everything is working well  No error but The notification is not coming on to Mobile .. I even track all current installation with Keys..

Comment: acctually i'm facing the some problem @whitehatboy ,did you find a solution ??

Answer (score 0):

You are missing one more configuration:

```
<receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="false">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
    <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
    <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```